# Worklight Push Notification for multiple user

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created an Push Notification application in IBM's Worklight in which it is sending notification for only one user's device(Android Device).How I can send Push notification to multiple user's devices?If any one created application then provide me some sample.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight server must know user's identity in order to be able to send push notifications. In case you did not define any user authentication in your application, Worklight server will use an "anonymous" user identity - a persistent cookie created on first application launch. This is considered an unauthenticated access.
In case this is the model you want to use you need to declare an EventSource in your adapter which does not require authentication (do not specify securityTest for it) and then use WL.Server.notifyAll(eventSource, options) API. 
This will send notification to users that are subscribed to a specified event source.

Source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=462167&tstart=360

Comment: are sure there is a `WL.Server.notifyAll()`? It's not in the Knowledge Center ... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-1-0-1-6&lang=en ... are you thinking of `WL.Server.notifyAllDevices()` ?

Comment: Way to go to bring back an old question! Yes, alldevices.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification works on Android and iOS only.
You can see how to implement on iOS in the push notifications module.
You can find the module at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/index.html#advanced

Comment: Hi @ravidor , I have alreday implemented Push Notification for Android,but its working for only one user's devices. I want to send notification to multiple user's device.But in Worklight there is no API like "notifyAlluser" also I am not getting ID of the user when I use WL.setActiveUser() method.I am using Developer Edition of IBM Worklight

Answer (score 0):

What I did to accomplish this is to save in a backend database all the users subscribed to a specific event source then send notifications to each of them.

I checked the Worklight info center and  WL.Server.notifyAll(eventSource, options) api is not listed!!